# vb.net saving a web binary to a file

Tags: vb.net, rest, memorystream

I have a web REST service that I am trying to extract an image (or a wav file) from.
I can get the image (jpg) via a memory stream and display it to a picture box, and then save the picture box to a file. 
What I want to do is eliminate the intermediate step of using picture box and save the memory stream straight to a file. However, the resultant file does not seem to be a jpg file.
When opening it throws a corrupted file error.

the code I have is as follows:

```
        Dim msgURI As String
        msgURI = "http://192.168.0.1/attachment/12345/0"

        Dim Pic As New PictureBox()

        Dim web_client As New WebClient()
        web_client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("XX", "XX")
        Dim image_stream As New MemoryStream(web_client.DownloadData(msgURI))
        Pic.Image = Image.FromStream(image_stream)


        Dim bm As Bitmap = Pic.Image
        Dim filename As String = "c:\temp\test.jpg"
        bm.Save(filename, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

and that works fine.

However when I use the following to bypass the bitmap and picturebox:

```
        Using file As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
            Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(image_stream.Length - 1) {}
            image_stream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(image_stream.Length))
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            image_stream.Close()
        End Using
```

I get a file that is a corrupted jpg file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Terry

Answer (score 0):

The `WebClient.DownloadData` method returns a byte array.  As such, it seems awfully silly to load the byte array into a memory stream just to read it out again into another byte array, just to then save it to a file.  All of that could easily be accomplished by going directly from the first byte array to a file, like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\temp\test.jpg", web_client.DownloadData(msgURI))
```

However, even that is inefficient since you could stream the data directly from the web to a file, like this:

```
web_client.DownloadFile(msgURI, "c:\temp\test.jpg")
```